# how to use a relative path to switch over to a different drive

Tags: c++, path, relative-path, drives

A method I am using to import images requires me to use a relative path but the pictures I would like to import are on a different drive. I'm not sure if there is a way for me to access that location using a relative path. If not can someone please tell me another way.

Comment: Requiring relative paths sounds like an artificial requirement imposed by either you or the person who wrote the function being used for import. I see little logical reason to restrict loading data from a relative path.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that Unix style operating systems do not have drives, I assume that you are using Windows. I do not think you can do that without "cheating". If that is really the only way, I would try to create a symbolic link to this other drive in a location on the origin drive file system. Symbolic links are rare on Windows, but can be created using the mklink command on Windows 7, 2008 and above using the mklink command. After that, you can access your files through a relative path inside the same drive.

Not sure if that will work for you, but worth a try.